# jQuery click handlers not triggered inside a modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, modal-dialog, simplemodal

I have a very simple click handler that makes an AJAX `GET` request on click like so:

```
$('span.switch-option').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('div.log-in-option').hide();
    $(this).parents('div.log-in-option').siblings('div.log-in-option').fadeIn();
});
```

This works perfectly anywhere else on the website. However, when I try to click a `<span>` element with the class `switch-option` inside a modal window, the event does not fire. Entering the contents of the click-handler function in the console and running them does perform the desired behavior, however.

Why will the click handler not fire in this modal window? I am using the popular SimpleModal plugin http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/ and jQuery 1.9.1.

A live example is here: http://ec2-107-22-8-70.compute-1.amazonaws.com/thread/19. If you click the `50,000 reps` or any user's reputation then try to click the big blue link in the dialog, the click handler does not fire. This behavior happens with other click handlers in different modal windows as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your script(main.js) is running the elements `'li.log-in, a.log-in'` does not exists in the dom, they are loaded dynamically when the popup is created thus jQuery is not able to bind the event handlers

Try event propagation

```
$(document).on('click', 'li.log-in, a.log-in', function() {
        $.get('/login/', function(data) {
            //make a modal window with the html
            $.modal(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Trying this now. I also updated the JS code in the intitial question because I c/p'd the wrong click handler, but it doesn't change the question at all.

Comment: Edit: just did it, works beautifully. You are a wizard, and the explanation makes sense. I feel like a dummy now.

Comment: @wnajar see the updated answer and you can search in web for dynamic elements and event handling using jquery there are lot of question handling the same in SO itself and other resources are available in web